# parse_dates causes grid() to be displaced

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code is a sample showing how the problem arises.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    #Reading data
    data = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv",parse_dates=['date'])
    data = data.iloc[0:17, :]

    #Plotting data
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.plot(data['date'],data['y'],'-o')

    ax.set(xlabel='Date', ylabel='y')
    ax.grid()

    plt.show()
```

The result is the following: the grid is displaced with respect to data point [grid_displaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgh2V.png).

If I remove `,parse_dates=['date']`, everything works fine [grid_not_displaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADrgp.png).

Here is the link to the data file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWcyIKgtDY_xkT_gaUxsiwjq9vLGfMog/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The grid is not "displaced". The grid is always where the ticks are. In the first case the ticks are every two days. In the second case the ticks are at each category (because matplotlib does not know that those categories are dates).

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I am a beginner.